# (urls.E004). Your URL Pattern is invalid in project level urls.py file

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am newbie to Django. I am getting the below error in-spite of rightly mapping the app level urls.py file to project level urls.py. Please help.

projectlevel\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include ('app_space.urls'))
]
```

applevel\urls.py

```
from importlib.resources import path
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('app_space/', views.home_page)
]
```

Error:

```
ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern <contextlib._GeneratorContextManager 
object at 0x0000024F8075D548> is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is 
a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.
```

Comment: Can you show us, your urls.py app level please ?

Comment: @Chaitanya Krishna Reddy did you register the app_space app in settings.py (INSTALLED_APPS list)?

Comment: @Herlock Below is my urls.py at app level

`from importlib.resources import path
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page)
]`

Comment: You must add app_name = "app_space" just before your url_pattern (in urls.py app level) and register your app in settings :)

Comment: @inquirer Yes. 

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app_space.apps.AppSpaceConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]`

Comment: You just need to call app_space like this in installed_apps : INSTALLED_APPS = [stuff..., 'app_space']

Comment: @Herlock  app_name is specified in apps.py file. 

`class AppSpaceConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'app_space'`

Comment: Your urlpatterns variable is a list of `importlib.resources.path` objects instead of `django.urls.path`... (You've written `from importlib.resources import path`, perhaps have a look at what your IDE suggests to you instead of letting it take control of the steering wheel?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in MainProjectFolder(where settings.py exists)/urls:

```
path('', include ('app_space.urls'))
```

and inside your **app_space/urls.py** you can but a custom url like **app_space/**

also make sure you import include and path

```
from django.urls import path, include
```

also add this line to settings.py/INSTALLED_APP -> 'app_space',

app_space -> your app name

Answer (score 2):

You should import `path` and `include` from `django.urls` in your app's urls.py so:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.home_page) 
]
```